# iOS stops tracking location after sometimes when in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using Xcode9. When I try to track locations it stops after sometime when the App is in the background. I've enabled location in capabilities in background mode.

In locationManager:didUpdateLocations: I stop the location with a timer(10 seconds) to avoid calling frequently. And restart with a timer(20 seconds). With the location I get I calculate the distance and save in database. How can I calculate and save in database while running the App in the background without stopping?

```
_locationManager = [ CLLocationManager new ];
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
_locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;
_locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;

if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
{
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    // I get locations in an array and use them to get distance

    restartLocationTimer 20second; // startUpdatingLocation
    stopLocationTimer 10second; // stopUpdatingLocation
}
```

Comment: Update the location each 9 min with a timer, during background. it will keep it alive.

Comment: Your question title says your location updates stops in background while your question says how to update DB in background without stopping location updates (That means location update is being triggered constantly I believe) which is no where in sync with title! Finally whats the relationship between saving data in background thread and location update being triggered? Why do u need to stop location updates to update DB ?

Comment: Finally All I see is configuration of location manager. code to make location manager start observing location update (StartUpdatingLocation/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges) is not shown in question. It is very difficult to answer a question without proper info. In case if it helps : you should use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges to monitor the location updates in background and when user terminates the app. Unless you are showing some kind of map to user in which case u can use StartUpdatingLocation but will not work when app is terminated

Comment: – Sandeep Bhandari Thanks you for replying. I am storing them in database so that I can show a history view with the details i got, with details such as  Start, End as a trip and also i am showing map while tracking. 
I don't want to terminate the App unless user double tap and swipes close the App. I want the App to keep running in background and track the locations. I set timer to stop location to avoid battery drain.
If I use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges will the App go to sleep? If so how can i get the locations and distance in sleep.